# Update a Google Map Marker position by it's ID

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating Google Map Markers and assigning them an ID as follows:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude),
             map: map,
             id: data.ID
});
```

This results in the markers appearing on the map however I also want to update the position of the markers at a later time, how can I grab a marker by the ID I have assigned to it and then update it's position?

I understand you can update the position with setPosition(latlng:LatLng) on the marker object in the Google API but how do I grab the marker by it's ID?

Comment: Maybe you could work with .filter() here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
 <script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-API-KEY&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            var long = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidlog').val();
            var lati = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidlat').val();

            var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long);
                var map;
                map_initialize();
                function map_initialize() {


                    var googleMapOptions =
                    {
                        center: mapCenter,
                        zoom: 18,
                        panControl: true,
                        zoomControl: true,
                        zoomControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                        },
                        scaleControl: true,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: mapCenter,
                        title: "Event Map"
                    });
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
                    marker.setMap(map);
                }
                var getCen = map.getCenter();
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
                    map.setCenter(getCen);
                });

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_initialize());

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizingMap());

                $('#showmap').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
                    resizeMap();
                })

                function resizeMap() {
                    if (typeof map == "undefined") return;
                    setTimeout(function () { resizingMap(); }, 400);
                }

                function resizingMap() {
                    if (typeof map == "undefined") return;
                    var center = map.getCenter();
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                    map.setCenter(center);
                }
            });

    </script>
```